# QR Scan on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, qr-code, barcode-scanner, scanning

I've been trying for some time to find a decent tutorial on how to can QR codes with Windows Phone 8. Unfortunately all of them, (at least those I found, which was a big load), were meant for WP7 and didn't work.

Some of them required a `PhotoLuminance` object, which is not available within the ZXing.net library.

I think my biggest problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the ImageStream from the camera, on the go and then scan it every second or so.

I need something that is fluent, without having to start a cameratask :).

Right now, I'm capturing the image to a rectangle using the VideoBrush component, so retrieving data from the camera is working.

```
camera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
viewfinderBrush.SetSource(camera);
```

I'm using this as a last resort, I really hope someone has a sample code out there or an idea on how I should approach this

Answer (score 0):

Try the below given code with ZXing.Net library.

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="grdCamera">
    <Rectangle x:Name="_previewRect" 
           Margin="0" 
           Height="800" 
           Width="600" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="_previewVideo">
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform  
                    x:Name="_previewTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
private PhotoCameraLuminanceSource _luminance;
private QRCodeReader _reader;
private PhotoCamera _photoCamera;

//Constructor
public ScanPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    _timer.Tick += (o, arg) => ScanPreviewBuffer();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _photoCamera = new PhotoCamera();
    _photoCamera.Initialized += OnPhotoCameraInitialized;
    _previewVideo.SetSource(_photoCamera);

    CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += (o, arg) => _photoCamera.Focus();

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private void OnPhotoCameraInitialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Width);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Height);

    _luminance = new PhotoCameraLuminanceSource(width, height);
    _reader = new QRCodeReader();

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        _previewTransform.Rotation = _photoCamera.Orientation;
        _timer.Start();
    });
}

private void ScanPreviewBuffer()
{
    try
    {
        _photoCamera.GetPreviewBufferY(_luminance.PreviewBufferY);
        var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(_luminance);
        var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
        var result = _reader.decode(binBitmap);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(result.Text));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: See the page http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/ for a definition of PhotoCameraLuminanceSource